# Is there a Facebook Share button event for FB.Event.subscribe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I'm looking to split test clicks between the Facebook Like button and Facebook Share button. I know I can attach an event handler of FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',...) to track clicks on the Facebook like button, but is there a corresponding event for the Facebook share button? There doesn't appear to be on in the FB.Event.subscribe documentation.

Answer (score 15):

There is no event for this - if you need to be notified when a user clicks shares from within your app, you should create your own share button and display the Feed/Share dialog when clicked:

```
$('#shareButton').click(function() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
        caption: 'An example caption',
    }, function(response){
        if (response === null) {
            console.log('was not shared');
        } else {
            console.log('shared - post id is ' + response.post_id);
        }
    });
});
```